# GCP - How can I Implement OAuth2 flow (Authorization Token Exchange) by using Email/Password provider of Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openid-connect, identity, idp

We want to use GCP for user authentication based on OIDC standard - OAuth2 Flow/Authorization code flow (server flow), where first step to get Auth Code and then in next Step to get ID Token/JWT.

We want to have our users records in goggle Cloud itself, like username : ABCD (some unique name) and Password: xyz
Users could be just a unique String, having some password set.

Now in google Cloud I have added provider as "email/password provider".

Questions :

1. I have a browser application where I have UI page and server side java code.
   On UI I have a login button, on click I call a server side endpoint of my java code called "/login" from where I want to call GCP and use that "email/password provider".
   In case we have multiple providers added on GCP, how to make sure that it will call "email/password provider" only.
2. Suppose I managed to call email password provider from server side java code ie from "/login" endpoint, will it return me an Auth Code first? I dont want ID token directly.
   Is there a way I can implement OAuth2 Flow/Authorization code flow using email/passowrd provider.

Comment: You should never ever store username and password in any circumstance. Look for any password leak news, and you'll see this is the main error the developers did.

Comment: Srsly, don't store the passwords.